# Sort the Whole Group Based On Date

Tags: sql

I have data following data, where i want to sort whole group based on date.

```
Create Table CustomerData
(
 Id Integer,
 GroupId Varchar(25),
 CName Varchar(25),
 Product Varchar(25),
 StartDate Date,
 EndDate Date,
 Premium Integer,
 GroupMo Varchar(25)
)

Insert Into CustomerData Values(1,'U001','Uday Dodiya','Motor Policy','2021-08- 
19','2022-08-18',2500,'9601629656')
Insert Into CustomerData Values(2,'K001','Kalpesh Shah','Health Policy','2021-08- 
02','2022-08-01',500,'9911629656')
Insert Into CustomerData Values(3,'U001','Brinda Dodiya','PA Policy','2021-08-02','2022- 
08-01',200,'9601629656')
Insert Into CustomerData Values(4,'Z001','Zalak Mer','PA Policy','2021-08-16','2022-08- 
15',2500,'9801629656')
Insert Into CustomerData Values(5,'H001','Harsh Rathod','WC Policy','2021-08-02','2022- 
08-01',4500,'7788995566')
Insert Into CustomerData Values(6,'H001','Het Dodiya','Motor Policy','2021-08-29','2022- 
08-28',2900,'7788995566')
Insert Into CustomerData Values(7,'U001','Gopal Dodiya','Other Policy','2021-08- 
31','2022-08-30',3000,'9601629656')
Insert Into CustomerData Values(8,'U001','Gopal Dodiya','Motor Policy','2021-08- 
10','2022-08-09',9600,'9601629656')
Insert Into CustomerData Values(9,'K001','Karina Shah','Health Policy','2021-08- 
06','2022-08-05',2500,'9911629656')  
Insert Into CustomerData Values(10,'S001','Sneha Mer','Motor Policy','2021-08-26','2022- 
08-25',3600,'8866554466')
Insert Into CustomerData Values(11,'U001','Uday Dodiya','PA Policy','2021-08-20','2022- 
08-19',3500,'9601629656')
```

[image: Here]

Desired Output

[image]

In Above Output You See H001 has 01-08-2022 So they display first after K001 Has Also 01-08-2022 Than U001 has also 01-08-2022 and than Z001 has 15-08-2022 And S001 has 25-08-2022

And All Group Data Also In Sorted Internally.

Sort the groups by each group's minimum ending date, and then the items in the group by their ending date

Anyone Please Help In this

Thank You In Advance

Comment: Just sort the data (`ORDER BY`) by `GroupId` and `StartDate`

Comment: no if used Order By GrroupId And StartDate Not Get My Desired Output

Comment: Show us your current `GROUP BY` attempt.

Comment: Your desired output doesn't match what you describe. H001 comes first, but you say it should be after K001.

Comment: i dosent which come first if the both group first record enddate is same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try following query and it's give exact output what i need

```
SELECT [GroupId] ,[CName] ,[Id] ,[GroupMo] ,[Product] ,[StartDate] , 
[EndDate] FROM (
SELECT *, MIN([EndDate]) OVER (PARTITION BY [GroupId] Order By [EndDate]) 
AS MinEndDate
FROM CustomerData) t
ORDER BY MinEndDate
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic syntax used for writing the `SELECT` query with `ORDER BY` clause is as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM
CustomerData
ORDER BY EndDate ASC | DESC;
```

Comment: i know this syntax, but i can not get my desired output by my self so i asked the question

Comment: I don't understand what your desired output is? You want to sort the data by EndDate right?

Comment: yes i want to sort the data using enddate, but whole group will be sort you see in output based on first date whole group has been sort based on its first records enddate

Answer (score -1):

Ok, now I understood. You want to sort the groups by each group's minimum starting date, and then the items in the group by their starting date. So what you need is a subquery like this one:

```
SELECT * from CustomerData cust
    INNER JOIN
        (SELECT GroupId, MIN(StartDate) GroupStart from CustomerData
            GROUP BY GroupId) custgroup
        ON cust.GroupId = custgroup.GroupId
   ORDER BY custgroup.GroupStart, cust.StartDate
```

Comment: you understand my question properly but this query not give proper output it just sort based on startdate

Comment: you take the start date but i want to sort as per end date

Comment: Ok, just change that and use end date instead

Comment: i already do by changing end date but not give proper output it just sort based on startdate or enddate